# julia workflow with JIT compiler

Tags: julia, workflow, jit

I'v recently picked up Julia as a neat way to implement some computationally heavy projects. So far I'm quite impressed by both speed and convenience - however, there's one thing I sort of dislike: when a code becomes fairly large running scripts takes increasing amounts of time since the JIT compiler needs to compile all files time and time again (not only the modified ones as, e.g., in C++ with CMake). This slows down my development workflow - what's the most julian/best practice way to speed this up so that I avoid waiting (sometime exessive) time?

Comment: One common strategy to deal with this is to just use the same REPL and make incremental changes.

Comment: Work in the same REPL and use Revise.jl https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl for tracking changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the workflow outlined in the comments above (keep REPL open and use Revise.jl), this package might be helpful for you:

https://github.com/dmolina/DaemonMode.jl